# how to get view's id on linearLayout in android

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

i have many views (textview) in linearlayout 
i want each view id when i click on view
but i dont want to setonclicklistener with every view

anyidea for me ?

thanks

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewd1"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#111111"
        android:gravity="center"             
        android:text="SUN"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
...
many textviews
...

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why you dont want to use avail functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the attribute `android:onClick` to each view. (You should also probably explicitly set `android:clickable="true"`.) It might save typing to set up a style for all this, particularly if some of the other attributes are shared among the many TextViews. In your Activity, define a method:

```
public void methodNameUsedInOnClickAttribute(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    // do something with ID
}
```